# Dual monitor screen resolution can not be added

Tags: debian, multiple-monitors, resolution, xorg.conf

I am desperately trying to setup my system on Debian Wheezy with VGA card NVIDIA Quadro 600, and two monitors (*two monitors are exactly the same, same manufacture, size and model number)*. One monitor is connected via **HDMI** and the other with **VGA** cable. While the HDMI monitor works great with 1920x1080 resolution, the VGA monitor fails. What I have done so far:

1. I have followed nvidia driver installation from [Debian website](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers), and installed nvidia-glx and required kernels (DKMS and Linux headers).
2. `xrandr` also fails to add 1920x1080 `--addmode` to my desired output (being VGA monitor). `nvidia-settings` also does not include my desired resolution for the VGA monitor.
3. I have tried to manually add 1920x1080 to xorg.conf, while this effort improves the situation by adding some newer resolutions such as 1024x768, but it does not add my desired 1920x1080.

Here is my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file if it helps:

```
1 # nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig                                                                                                                                                                         
2 # nvidia-xconfig:  version 331.49  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-10)  Wed Feb 12 21:00:07 PST 2014
3 
4 Section "ServerLayout"
5     Identifier     "Layout0"
6     Screen      0  "Screen0"
7     InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
8     InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
9 EndSection
10 
11 Section "Files"
12 EndSection
13 
14 Section "InputDevice"
15     # generated from default
16     Identifier     "Mouse0"
17     Driver         "mouse"
18     Option         "Protocol" "auto"
19     Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
20     Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
21     Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
22 EndSection
23 
24 Section "InputDevice"
25     # generated from default
26     Identifier     "Keyboard0"
27     Driver         "kbd"
28 EndSection
29 
30 Section "Monitor"
31     Identifier     "DVI-I-0"
32     VendorName     "Unknown"
33     ModelName      "Unknown"
34     Modeline       "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
35 EndSection
36 
37 Section "Monitor"
38     Identifier     "DP-0"
39     VendorName     "Unknown"
40     ModelName      "Unknown"
41     Modeline       "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
42     Option         "RightOf" "DVI-I-0"
43 EndSection
44 
45 
46 Section "Device"
47     Identifier     "Device0"
48     Driver         "nvidia"
49     VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
50 EndSection
51 
52 Section "Screen"
53     Identifier     "Screen0"
54     Device         "Device0"
55     Monitor        "Monitor0"
56     DefaultDepth    24
57     SubSection     "Display"
58         Depth       24
59         Modes       "1920x1080"
60     EndSubSection
61 EndSection
62
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem may be caused by VGA connection. Try any digital cable if you can.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! the problem is now resolved based on your suggestions after just changing one VGA cable to another! For my future, it is perhaps wiser to look into more basic problems before diving into more complicated ones ;)